# C# Combine Regex Expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to combine a few expressions to get 3 different results per line.

Example:
`element\data\elements.data|44a0b61d1952973f52ad54cb911c0e3e|33095223`

`.*?element(?:(?!\|).)*` retrieves `element\data\elements.data`

`(?<=\|)(.*?)(?=\|)` retrieves `44a0b61d1952973f52ad54cb911c0e3e`

`(?<=\|)[0-9]*\r` retrieves `33095223`

But for me to get these I currently am doing 3 different RegEx, and I would like to limit it down to only one to get the 3 results I need and set them to different variables.

I have looked into doing a `Dictionary` but those only allow 2 variables, while I need 3.

Comment: The expressions `a`, `b` and `c` match `a`, `b` and `c` respectively. How do you match `abc`?

Comment: @GrantWinney How exactly would I achieve that?

Comment: I'm confused on your objection to using a Dictionary.  You can have `Dictionary<string,Collection<type>()>`, and if all of your parameters for retrieval are unique that would make a great key.

Comment: @FelixCastor could you give a quick example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just split on the vertical pipe:

```
var elements = string.Split('|');
```

The resulting string array would contain:

- element\data\elements.data
- 44a0b61d1952973f52ad54cb911c0e3e
- 33095223

Comment: +1 This worked perfectly, is there a way to set each string array to a variable? like `var file = "element\data\elements.data"`, `var hash = 44a0b61d1952973f52ad54cb911c0e3e`, and `var bytes = 33095223`

Answer (score 0):

For having a Regex with multiple matches you should take a look add | between your expressions.
This will then return you all the results matching any of the pattern, with no distinction which string was found by which match.